# JavaScript error coming only in IE 8 but no other browser

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I am using the following function in my code

```
function viewTearSheet(creativeId) {
    var url = "/Main?event_key=new_view_test_ad&isAjaxCall=true&fromCreateAdNewDesign=tear&"+"&creativeId=" + creativeId + "&testAdClick=primary";
    day = new Date();
    id = day.getTime();
    window.open(url, '" + id + "', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=1000,height=800,left = 320,top = 150');
}
```

It works for all the browsers except IE8.It give following error message in IE8

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0;
.NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Wed, 6 Feb 2013 07:06:38 UTC

Message: Invalid argument.
Line: 497
Char: 5
Code: 0
URI: https://test.juhu.abc.com/chakra/campaign/view.js?z=166
```

How can I resolve this..Thanks in advance..

Comment: what is there in line 497..in ur code?

Comment: Line 497 is the one with `window.open` I need to guess?

Answer (score 1):

The string `'" + id + "'` is no valid window name - spaces and plus signs are not allowed, I and strongly doubt quotes are. See also [ie8 var w= window.open() - "Message: Invalid argument."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710756/ie8-var-w-window-open-message-invalid-argument), [window.open throws invalid argument in IE7-8-9b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840369/window-open-throws-invalid-argument-in-ie7-8-9b) and [window.open invalid argument error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255909/window-open-invalid-argument-error)

Comment: yes. change this `(url, '" + id + "', 'tool...` to that `(url, 'win' + creativeId, 'tool...`

Answer (score 0):

Could be a red herring but in your code here you have multiple & symbols and an un needed + any reason for this try removing it as it couldbe the issue.

Instead off this

```
 var url = "/Main?event_key=new_view_test_ad&isAjaxCall=true&fromCreateAdNewDesign=tear&"+"&creativeId=" + creativeId + "&testAdClick=primary";
```

Ty this

```
var url = "/Main?event_key=new_view_test_ad&isAjaxCall=true&fromCreateAdNewDesign=tear&creativeId=" + creativeId + "&testAdClick=primary";
```

Also only normal charachters are allowed in window name so if your date is formated with - etc this will also break in ie 8, try replacing id with a normal string and see if the issue still happens. if so then that's your problem.

See Bergi's answer for more info